# Convert column with Month Name and Year to integer with format YYYYMM in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, date-conversion

I have a date column like the next one stored as `VARCHAR` (not `DATE` type) and I want to convert it to an `INTEGER` type with next format: `YYYYMM`. So, for example, if this where my sample data:

```
period
"January 2018"
"February 2018"
"March 2018"
```

I would like to get the next integers:

```
result
201801
201802
201803
```

I have tried the next code:

```
select
    period,
    str_to_date(period, '%M %Y') as yearperiod
from
    table
```

But this gives, for example, `2018-01-00` format which I would like to convert to the integer `201801`.

Comment: It seems like you want a [cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html) function?

Comment: IDK about mysql but certainly you can use `INSTR(trunc(str_to_date(period, '%M %Y'),'-'),0,LENGTH(trunc(str_to_date(period, '%M %Y'),'-')-2)`

Comment: thank you for responding

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the next sequence of **MySQL** methods:

**(1)** First apply `STR_TO_DATE(period, '%M %d %Y')`.

**(2)** Then apply `DATE_FORMAT(<previous_result>, "%Y%m")` to the previous result.

**(3)** And finally use `CONVERT(<previous_result>, UNSIGNED)` to do the integer cast over the previous result.

This is showed on the next example:

```
SELECT
    period,
    CONVERT(
      DATE_FORMAT(
        STR_TO_DATE(period, '%M %d %Y'),
        "%Y%m"
      ),
      UNSIGNED
    ) AS yearAndPeriod
FROM
    <table_name>
```

Also, you can check it here:

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pxaKDX6mHuRNfvUHqkUPou/1)

Comment: Do it works for you? In that case you can mark this as correct. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers