# Convert a 'string' type column(include brackets) to datetime in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, select

I have a table with one column like this below:
[original type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inbfg.png)

```
'03-Mar-2020 (10:29:28.225236)'
```

and now, I want to convert this column to datetime format below:
[target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvt7p.png)

```
'2020-03-03 10:33:00'
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT datetime, str_to_date(datetime,'%D %M %Y') as test 
FROM dublin.availability;
```

this code is from [re1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656671/convert-column-with-month-name-and-year-to-integer-with-format-yyyymm-in-mysql)

but it returns NULL to me. see this:[wrong1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqf28.png)

Comment: Were you expecting miracles?

Comment: Do you want just a date or do you want the time as well

Comment: date and time, just like what I give above. and the second converted to integer~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the string to a date with the following expression:

```
str_to_date(datetime, '%d-%b-%Y (%H:%i:%s.%f)')
```

If you want to get rid of the time part:

```
date(str_to_date(datetime, '%d-%b-%Y (%H:%i:%s.%f)'))
```

If you want to round to the nearest second:

```
cast(str_to_date(datetime, '%d-%b-%Y (%H:%i:%s.%f)') as datetime)
```

Comment: how could I convert the second from float to int as well? thx

Comment: @tanglai: do you want to round to the nearest second? I updated my answer.